# TreeView with VirtualToggleButtona and PreviewMouseDown. Odd behavior

Tags: wpf

After I read [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28306/Working-with-Checkboxes-in-the-WPF-TreeView) I decided to play with VirtualToggleButton and added two more boolean properties SuppressKeyboard and SuppressMouse to define whether e.Handled should be set to True.

Here's the code for changed VTB:

```
public static class VirtualToggleButton
    {
        #region attached properties

        #region IsChecked

        /// <summary>
        /// IsChecked Attached Dependency Property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsChecked", typeof(Nullable<bool>), typeof(VirtualToggleButton),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((Nullable<bool>)false,
                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Journal,
                    new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsCheckedChanged)));

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the IsChecked property.  This dependency property 
        /// indicates whether the toggle button is checked.
        /// </summary>
        public static Nullable<bool> GetIsChecked(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (Nullable<bool>)d.GetValue(IsCheckedProperty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the IsChecked property.  This dependency property 
        /// indicates whether the toggle button is checked.
        /// </summary>
        public static void SetIsChecked(DependencyObject d, Nullable<bool> value)
        {
            d.SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles changes to the IsChecked property.
        /// </summary>
        private static void OnIsCheckedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var pseudobutton = d as UIElement;
            if (pseudobutton != null)
            {
                var newValue = (Nullable<bool>)e.NewValue;
                if (newValue == true)
                {
                    RaiseCheckedEvent(pseudobutton);
                }
                else if (newValue == false)
                {
                    RaiseUncheckedEvent(pseudobutton);
                }
                else
                {
                    RaiseIndeterminateEvent(pseudobutton);
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region IsThreeState

        /// <summary>
        /// IsThreeState Attached Dependency Property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsThreeStateProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsThreeState", typeof(bool), typeof(VirtualToggleButton),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((bool)false));

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the IsThreeState property.  This dependency property 
        /// indicates whether the control supports two or three states.  
        /// IsChecked can be set to null as a third state when IsThreeState is true.
        /// </summary>
        public static bool GetIsThreeState(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (bool)d.GetValue(IsThreeStateProperty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the IsThreeState property.  This dependency property 
        /// indicates whether the control supports two or three states. 
        /// IsChecked can be set to null as a third state when IsThreeState is true.
        /// </summary>
        public static void SetIsThreeState(DependencyObject d, bool value)
        {
            d.SetValue(IsThreeStateProperty, value);
        }

        #endregion

        #region IsVirtualToggleButton

        /// <summary>
        /// IsVirtualToggleButton Attached Dependency Property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsVirtualToggleButtonProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsVirtualToggleButton", typeof(bool), typeof(VirtualToggleButton),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((bool)false,
                    new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsVirtualToggleButtonChanged)));

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the IsVirtualToggleButton property.  This dependency property 
        /// indicates whether the object to which the property is attached is treated as a VirtualToggleButton.  
        /// If true, the object will respond to keyboard and mouse input the same way a ToggleButton would.
        /// </summary>
        public static bool GetIsVirtualToggleButton(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (bool)d.GetValue(IsVirtualToggleButtonProperty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the IsVirtualToggleButton property.  This dependency property 
        /// indicates whether the object to which the property is attached is treated as a VirtualToggleButton.  
        /// If true, the object will respond to keyboard and mouse input the same way a ToggleButton would.
        /// </summary>
        public static void SetIsVirtualToggleButton(DependencyObject d, bool value)
        {
            d.SetValue(IsVirtualToggleButtonProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles changes to the IsVirtualToggleButton property.
        /// </summary>
        private static void OnIsVirtualToggleButtonChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var element = d as IInputElement;
            if (element != null)
            {
                if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                {
                    element.AddHandler(Mouse.PreviewMouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown));
                    element.PreviewKeyDown += OnPreviewKeyDown;
                }
                else
                {
                    element.RemoveHandler(Mouse.PreviewMouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown));
                    element.PreviewKeyDown -= OnPreviewKeyDown;
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region SuppressKeyboard

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SuppressKeyboardProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SuppressKeyboard", typeof (bool), typeof (VirtualToggleButton),
                                                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));

        public static bool GetSuppressKeyboard(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (bool)d.GetValue(SuppressKeyboardProperty);
        }

        public static void SetSuppressKeyboard(DependencyObject d, bool value)
        {
            d.SetValue(SuppressKeyboardProperty, value);
        }

        #endregion

        #region SuppressMouse

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SuppressMouseProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SuppressMouse", typeof(bool), typeof(VirtualToggleButton),
                                                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));

        public static bool GetSuppressMouse(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (bool)d.GetValue(SuppressMouseProperty);
        }

        public static void SetSuppressMouse(DependencyObject d, bool value)
        {
            d.SetValue(SuppressKeyboardProperty, value);
        }

        #endregion

        #endregion

        #region routed events

        #region Checked

        /// <summary>
        /// A static helper method to raise the Checked event on a target element.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="target">UIElement or ContentElement on which to raise the event</param>
        internal static RoutedEventArgs RaiseCheckedEvent(UIElement target)
        {
            if (target == null) 
                return null;

            var args = new RoutedEventArgs {RoutedEvent = ToggleButton.CheckedEvent};
            RaiseEvent(target, args);
            return args;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Unchecked

        /// <summary>
        /// A static helper method to raise the Unchecked event on a target element.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="target">UIElement or ContentElement on which to raise the event</param>
        internal static RoutedEventArgs RaiseUncheckedEvent(UIElement target)
        {
            if (target == null) return null;

            RoutedEventArgs args = new RoutedEventArgs();
            args.RoutedEvent = ToggleButton.UncheckedEvent;
            RaiseEvent(target, args);
            return args;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Indeterminate

        /// <summary>
        /// A static helper method to raise the Indeterminate event on a target element.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="target">UIElement or ContentElement on which to raise the event</param>
        internal static RoutedEventArgs RaiseIndeterminateEvent(UIElement target)
        {
            if (target == null) return null;

            RoutedEventArgs args = new RoutedEventArgs();
            args.RoutedEvent = ToggleButton.IndeterminateEvent;
            RaiseEvent(target, args);
            return args;
        }

        #endregion

        #endregion

        #region private methods

        private static void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left && e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                UpdateIsChecked(sender as DependencyObject);

                var dob = sender as DependencyObject;
                var suppress = dob != null && GetSuppressMouse(dob);
                e.Handled = suppress;
            }
        }

        private static void OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            var dob = sender as DependencyObject;
            var suppress = dob != null && GetSuppressKeyboard(dob);

            if (e.OriginalSource == sender)
            {
                if (e.Key == Key.Space)
                {
                    // ignore alt+space which invokes the system menu
                    if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Alt) == ModifierKeys.Alt) 
                        return;

                    UpdateIsChecked(sender as DependencyObject);
                    e.Handled = suppress;
                }
                else if (e.Key == Key.Enter && (bool)(sender as DependencyObject).GetValue(KeyboardNavigation.AcceptsReturnProperty))
                {
                    UpdateIsChecked(sender as DependencyObject);
                    e.Handled = suppress;
                }
            }
        }

        private static void UpdateIsChecked(DependencyObject d)
        {
            Nullable<bool> isChecked = GetIsChecked(d);
            if (isChecked == true)
            {
                SetIsChecked(d, GetIsThreeState(d) ? (Nullable<bool>)null : (Nullable<bool>)false);
            }
            else
            {
                SetIsChecked(d, isChecked.HasValue);
            }
        }

        private static void RaiseEvent(DependencyObject target, RoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (target is UIElement)
            {
                (target as UIElement).RaiseEvent(args);
            }
            else if (target is ContentElement)
            {
                (target as ContentElement).RaiseEvent(args);
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

I also changed a little the binding:

```
<TreeView>
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Property="cl:VirtualToggleButton.IsVirtualToggleButton" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Property="cl:VirtualToggleButton.SuppressKeyboard" Value="True"/>
                    <!--<Setter Property="cl:VirtualToggleButton.SuppressMouse" Value="True"/>-->
                </Style>
            </TreeView.Resources>

            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Softwares}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <CheckBox Focusable="False" 
                                          IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}
                                                                    , Path=(cl:VirtualToggleButton.IsChecked), Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Height="Auto"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

        </TreeView>
```

Here comes very strange thing. 
When SuppressMouse is set and TreeViewItems is clicked it's not selected (and this is consistent behavior), IsChecked set to True, but CheckBox stays unchecked. 
I really have no idea why it is so because everything works well when keyboard is used.
When SuppressMouse = False CheckBox changes its statate as it should, BUT OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown is called twice for each clicked TreeViewItem. And this is also very confusing.

Question: What are the causes of the described behavior

Comment: Question: What are the causes of the described behavior

Comment: Well, I am a fool. PreviewMouseDown goes from the upper node, so IsChecked is set to this node not that was hit. I'd use bubbled event.

Comment: you figured it out, so I'd say you're NOT a fool :) please post an answer and accept it when you get it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, original version of the VirtualToggleButton used bubbling event for MouseLeftButtonDown.
What I really don't like is the chance for the clicked control to mark event as handled. And it is the case in the given article cause selection of TreeViewItem doesn't raise mousedown event handler. So I decided to use tunneling events but introduced the bug forgetting to check the sender and the source of the event: root TreeViewItem set its state as Checked whereas child item was clicked.

I added several more properties to control whether events are allowed to propagate through elements tree and how button is toggled ( keyboard or/and mouse).

The final version of VTB:

```
public static class VirtualToggleButton
    {
        #region attached properties

        #region IsChecked

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsChecked", typeof(Nullable<bool>), typeof(VirtualToggleButton),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((Nullable<bool>)false,
                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Journal,
                    new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsCheckedChanged)));

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the IsChecked property.  This dependency property 
        /// indicates whether the toggle button is checked.
        /// </summary>
        public static Nullable<bool> GetIsChecked(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (Nullable<bool>)d.GetValue(IsCheckedProperty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the IsChecked property.  This dependency property 
        /// indicates whether the toggle button is checked.
        /// </summary>
        public static void SetIsChecked(DependencyObject d, Nullable<bool> value)
        {
            d.SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles changes to the IsChecked property.
        /// </summary>
        private static void OnIsCheckedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var pseudobutton = d as UIElement;
            if (pseudobutton != null)
            {
                var newValue = (Nullable<bool>)e.NewValue;
                if (newValue == true)
                {
                    RaiseCheckedEvent(pseudobutton);
                }
                else if (newValue == false)
                {
                    RaiseUncheckedEvent(pseudobutton);
                }
                else
                {
                    RaiseIndeterminateEvent(pseudobutton);
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region IsThreeState

        /// <summary>
        /// IsThreeState Attached Dependency Property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsThreeStateProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsThreeState", typeof(bool), typeof(VirtualToggleButton),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((bool)false));

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the IsThreeState property.  This dependency property 
        /// indicates whether the control supports two or three states.  
        /// IsChecked can be set to null as a third state when IsThreeState is true.
        /// </summary>
        public static bool GetIsThreeState(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (bool)d.GetValue(IsThreeStateProperty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the IsThreeState property.  This dependency property 
        /// indicates whether the control supports two or three states. 
        /// IsChecked can be set to null as a third state when IsThreeState is true.
        /// </summary>
        public static void SetIsThreeState(DependencyObject d, bool value)
        {
            d.SetValue(IsThreeStateProperty, value);
        }

        #endregion

        #region IsVirtualToggleButton

        /// <summary>
        /// IsVirtualToggleButton Attached Dependency Property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsVirtualToggleButtonProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsVirtualToggleButton", typeof(bool), typeof(VirtualToggleButton),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((bool)false,
                    new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsVirtualToggleButtonChanged)));

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the IsVirtualToggleButton property.  This dependency property 
        /// indicates whether the object to which the property is attached is treated as a VirtualToggleButton.  
        /// If true, the object will respond to keyboard and mouse input the same way a ToggleButton would.
        /// </summary>
        public static bool GetIsVirtualToggleButton(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (bool)d.GetValue(IsVirtualToggleButtonProperty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the IsVirtualToggleButton property.  This dependency property 
        /// indicates whether the object to which the property is attached is treated as a VirtualToggleButton.  
        /// If true, the object will respond to keyboard and mouse input the same way a ToggleButton would.
        /// </summary>
        public static void SetIsVirtualToggleButton(DependencyObject d, bool value)
        {
            d.SetValue(IsVirtualToggleButtonProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles changes to the IsVirtualToggleButton property.
        /// </summary>
        private static void OnIsVirtualToggleButtonChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var element = d as IInputElement;
            if (element != null)
            {
                if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                {
                    element.AddHandler(Mouse.PreviewMouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnPrevieMouseLeftButtonDown));
                    element.PreviewKeyDown += OnPreviewKeyDown;
                }
                else
                {
                    element.RemoveHandler(Mouse.PreviewMouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnPrevieMouseLeftButtonDown));
                    element.PreviewKeyDown -= OnPreviewKeyDown;
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region SuppressKeyboard

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SuppressKeyboardProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SuppressKeyboard", typeof(bool), typeof(VirtualToggleButton),
                                                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));

        public static bool GetSuppressKeyboard(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (bool)d.GetValue(SuppressKeyboardProperty);
        }

        public static void SetSuppressKeyboard(DependencyObject d, bool value)
        {
            d.SetValue(SuppressKeyboardProperty, value);
        }

        #endregion

        #region SuppressMouse

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SuppressMouseProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SuppressMouse", typeof(bool), typeof(VirtualToggleButton),
                                                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));

        public static bool GetSuppressMouse(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (bool)d.GetValue(SuppressMouseProperty);
        }

        public static void SetSuppressMouse(DependencyObject d, bool value)
        {
            d.SetValue(SuppressKeyboardProperty, value);
        }

        #endregion

        #region IsToggledByMouse

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsToggledByMouseProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsToggledByMouse", typeof(bool), typeof(VirtualToggleButton),
                                                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true));

        public static bool GetIsToggledByMouse(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (bool)d.GetValue(IsToggledByMouseProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsToggledByMouse(DependencyObject d, bool value)
        {
            d.SetValue(IsToggledByMouseProperty, value);
        }

        #endregion

        #region IsToogledByKeyboard

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsToggledByKeyboardProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsToggledByKeyboard", typeof(bool), typeof(VirtualToggleButton),
                                                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true));

        public static bool GetIsToggledByKeyboard(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (bool)d.GetValue(IsToggledByKeyboardProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsToggledByKeyboard(DependencyObject d, bool value)
        {
            d.SetValue(IsToggledByKeyboardProperty, value);
        }

        #endregion

        #endregion

        #region routed events

        #region Checked

        internal static RoutedEventArgs RaiseCheckedEvent(UIElement target)
        {
            if (target == null)
                return null;

            var args = new RoutedEventArgs { RoutedEvent = ToggleButton.CheckedEvent };
            RaiseEvent(target, args);
            return args;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Unchecked

        /// <summary>
        /// A static helper method to raise the Unchecked event on a target element.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="target">UIElement or ContentElement on which to raise the event</param>
        internal static RoutedEventArgs RaiseUncheckedEvent(UIElement target)
        {
            if (target == null) return null;

            RoutedEventArgs args = new RoutedEventArgs();
            args.RoutedEvent = ToggleButton.UncheckedEvent;
            RaiseEvent(target, args);
            return args;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Indeterminate

        /// <summary>
        /// A static helper method to raise the Indeterminate event on a target element.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="target">UIElement or ContentElement on which to raise the event</param>
        internal static RoutedEventArgs RaiseIndeterminateEvent(UIElement target)
        {
            if (target == null) return null;

            RoutedEventArgs args = new RoutedEventArgs();
            args.RoutedEvent = ToggleButton.IndeterminateEvent;
            RaiseEvent(target, args);
            return args;
        }

        #endregion

        #endregion

        #region private methods

        private static void OnPrevieMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            // Looking for the logically closest (up in elements tree) element
            // Like a bubble in a tunneling event
            var senderType = sender.GetType();
            var depObj = e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject;
            while (depObj != null && depObj.GetType() != senderType)
                depObj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(depObj);

            if (depObj != sender)
                return;

            if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left && e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                var dob = sender as DependencyObject;
                var suppress = dob != null && GetSuppressMouse(dob);
                e.Handled = suppress;

                if (!GetIsToggledByMouse(depObj))
                    return;

                UpdateIsChecked(sender as DependencyObject);
            }
        }

        private static void OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key != Key.Space && e.Key != Key.Enter )
                return;

            var senderType = sender.GetType();
            var p = e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject;
            while (p != null && p.GetType() != senderType)
                p = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(p);

            if (p != sender)
                return;

            var dob = sender as DependencyObject;
            var suppress = dob != null && GetSuppressKeyboard(dob);

            if (e.Key == Key.Space)
            {
                // ignore alt+space which invokes the system menu
                if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Alt) == ModifierKeys.Alt)
                    return;

                UpdateIsChecked(sender as DependencyObject);
                e.Handled = suppress;
            }
            else if (e.Key == Key.Enter && (bool)(sender as DependencyObject).GetValue(KeyboardNavigation.AcceptsReturnProperty))
            {
                UpdateIsChecked(sender as DependencyObject);
                e.Handled = suppress;
            }

        }

        private static void UpdateIsChecked(DependencyObject d)
        {
            Nullable<bool> isChecked = GetIsChecked(d);
            if (isChecked == true)
            {
                SetIsChecked(d, GetIsThreeState(d) ? (Nullable<bool>)null : (Nullable<bool>)false);
            }
            else
            {
                SetIsChecked(d, isChecked.HasValue);
            }
        }

        private static void RaiseEvent(DependencyObject target, RoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (target is UIElement)
            {
                (target as UIElement).RaiseEvent(args);
            }
            else if (target is ContentElement)
            {
                (target as ContentElement).RaiseEvent(args);
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```